# Raspberry pi 3, IR remote error : transmission failed

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi3, lirc

I am using Debian on Raspberry Pi 3. I am trying to create IR remote.
I am following online tutorials. 
I could record my remote using IR receiver but while emitting IR, I am getting following error:

```
irsend:  command failed: SEND_ONCE Samsung KEY_POWER
irsend: transmission failed
```

I tried everything I could using google, but no progress.

[image: error. message]

[image: wring setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and trying do many different things, finally i found the solution. There were several problems in my configuration. The two steps below fixed my problem:

1) Raspberry pi default gpio control was overriding lirc configuration. To solve this i restarted lirc using below command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lirc restart
```

2) Set lirc device manually

```
sudo lircd --device /dev/lirc0
```

Also i used 1k resister instead of 10 k in setup.

Thanks anyway!

set my lirc device mannualy